# looping array with ES6 in React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to return some new HTML from a react function. But I can seem to get the syntax correct. I assume there needs to be one more return statement somewhere.

I get the following error

> ConnectedList(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually
> means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return
> null.
>
> When adding return statement in front of user.map I get
> TypeError: user.map is not a function

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    console.log("List state", state);
  return { user: state.users };
};


const ConnectedList = ({ user }) => {
  console.log("user object",user);

  /* return */user.map((user, index) => {
    console.log("test", user);
    return (<div>user info: {user.user}</div>)
  }
  )
}

const List = connect(mapStateToProps)(ConnectedList);

export default List;
```

Here is the store that it's fetching the information from.

```
export default {
    "users":[
        {"id":1, "user": "Test user 1"}, 
        {"id":2, "user": "Test user 2"}
    ]
    }
```

UserActions.js

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import axios from 'axios';
import users from '../store/store';

export const UPDATE_USER = 'users:updateUser';
export const NEW_USER = 'users:newUser';

export function updateUser(newUser)  {
    console.log("newUser: ", newUser);
    return {
        type: UPDATE_USER,
        payload: users
    }
}
```

userReducer.js

```
import {UPDATE_USER, NEW_USER} from '../actions/userActions';

export default function userReducer(state = '', {type, payload}) {
    console.log("payload:",payload);
    switch (type) {
        case UPDATE_USER:
            return payload;
        case NEW_USER:
            return payload;
        default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to print the result of the map.

Comment: What does `console.log("user object",user);` output? You say it's an object? `map()` will not work then.

Comment: Yes fixed it by using var arr = $.map(user, function(el) { return el }); but that is kind of ugly is there a nicer way?

Comment: Well, if your users are an object, you could use `for ... of users` or `Object.keys(users).map()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ConnectedList` doesn't return antyhing:

```
const ConnectedList = ({ user }) => {
  console.log("user object",user);

  return user.map((user, index) => {
      console.log("test", user);
      return (<div key={index}>user info: {user.user}</div>)
    }
  )
}
```

You will also need to assign [`key`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) to each element in the array.

Comment: TypeError: user.map is not a function when I try this.

Comment: @user2130951 Then probably `user` is not an array. Maybe it's `undefined` or `null`.

Comment: Yeah, @user2130951 show us your reducer and how you configured them.